# Parsing SOAP response using SAVON response.to_hash conversion method

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I am having trouble parsing a SOAP response.

Here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new "http://1.2.3.4/xyz/abcd/fsds.wsdl"

res = client.query_unpaid_assesments do |soap,wsse|
  soap.namespaces["xmlns:SOAP-ENV"] = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  soap.namespaces["xmlns:xsi"] = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  soap.namespaces["xmlns:xsd"] = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

  wsse.username="xyz"
  wsse.password="123"

  soap.body = {:orderNumber => 111222333 }
end

response = Savon::Response#to_hash
hres = response.to_hash 
all_data = hres[:response][:asses_data][:date][:amount][:assesReference][:year][:cusOffCode][:serie][:number][:date][:time]
```

Here is the error that I am having:

undefined method `to_hash` for Savon::Response:Class (NoMethodError)

"res" is giving me xml response that I would like to have in hash.

I read previous related questions and they recommending to use response.to_hash , which I did and is throwing the error specified above.
How can i get rid of this error and have my response into hash.

thanks for ur help

I forgot to post the body of the xml response that I would like to parse:

```
<soapenv:Body>
<response>
<ns203:assesData xmlns:ns203="http://asdfsd.sdfsd.zbc.org">
<ns203:date>2010-09-01</ns203:date>
<ns203:amount>34400</ns203:amount>
<ns203:asesReference>
    <ns203:year>2010</ns203:year>
    <ns203:cusOffCode>098</ns203:customsOfficeCode>
    <ns203:serie>F</ns203:serie>
    <ns203:number>524332</ns203:number>
    <ns203:date>2010-11-11</ns203:date>
    <ns203:time>10:11:103</ns203:time>
</ns203:assesReference>
</ns203:assesData>
</response>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to be trying to #to_hash `res` itself, the returned Savon::Response object, instead of the Savon::Response class.

So `hres = res.to_hash` should work.

An example I found (at the end of here: http://blog.nofail.de/2010/01/savon-vs-handsoap-calling-a-service/) should give you the idea.

```
class SavonBankCode
  def self.zip_code(bank_code)
    client = Savon::Client.new Shootout.endpoints[:bank_code][:uri]
    response = client.get_bank { |soap| soap.body = { "wsdl:blz" => bank_code } }
    response.to_hash[:get_bank_response][:details][:plz]
  end
end
```

An alternative would be to parse the result with Nokogiri or similar, meaning you could do something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
response = res.xpath("//ns203:assesData", "ns203" => "http://asdfsd.sdfsd.zbc.org")
date = response.xpath("ns203:date", "ns203" => "http://asdfsd.sdfsd.zbc.org")
amount = response.xpath("ns203:amount", "ns203" => "http://asdfsd.sdfsd.zbc.org")
number = response.xpath("ns203:asesReference/ns203:number", "ns203" => "http://asdfsd.sdfsd.zbc.org")
```

etc. etc. Ugly as sin of course, but hey it is an (untested or refined) alternative ;)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `response.body`.
It returns a hash