# Display multiple hash keys notation

Tags: ruby, hash, savon, notation

Let's say i have a ruby hash in the style of savon soap xml response to hash

```
   hash1= { node1­: {node­2:{node3:1­,node4:2}}­}
```

now to display this hash

```
hash1[:nod­e1][:node2­][:node3]
```

works and outputs => 1

```
hash1[:nod­e1][:node2­][:node4]
```

works and output => 2

```
hash1[:nod­e1][:node2­][:node3][:node4]
```

gives TypeError

although i have seen that type of code on savon scripts. What doesnt it work in my situation ?

Answer (score 2):

`hash1[:nod­e1][:node2­][:node3][:node4]` is calling the method [] on

`hash1[:nod­e1][:node2­][:node3]`.

Its the equivalent of trying `1[:node4]`. The method  on an integer takes a Fixnum and cannot implicitly convert a symbol (or a string etc) into an integer.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail please? I dont understand. Where can i find this [] method documented? Also, I saw this code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153215/parsing-soap-response-using-savon-response-to-hash-conversion-method) where in the last line he does all_data = hres[:response][:asses_data][:date][:amount][:assesReference][:year][:cusOffCode][:serie][:number][:date][:time]. How is that possible there and not in my example?

Comment: osman is referring to the the method [Fixnum#[]](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: thnx for pointing that out, but i still dont understand how its used in a hash from savon that has the same structure as mine, and i cant use that on my hash. I don't understand what that method does in that context. If someone could explain it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

These multiply-nested hashes are difficult to read, aren't they?  Let's spread your hash out a bit:

```
hash1= { 
  node1­: {
    node­2: { node3:1­, node4:2 }
    }­
  }
```

So: The value of node1 is itself a hash. The only entry in that hash, node2, also has a hash for a value.  This hash has two entries: node3 and node4, both of which have integers as values.

So `hash1[:node1][:node2]` returns `{node3:1, node4:2}`. And `hash1[:node1][:node2][:node3]` returns 1.

But `hash1[:node1][:node2][:node3][:node4]` doesn't make any sense, because 1 isn't a hash, and therefore doesn't have a key `:node4`.  That key belongs to the `:node2` hash.

It *would* make sense if you had `hash1= { node1­: {node­2: {node3: {node4:2} }}­}`.  But you don't.

Like I said: these nested hashes are a pain to read...

Comment: This makes perfect sense, although the reason i'm asking is not because I find them difficult to read, but because  I saw this code here where in the last line he does all_data = hres[:response][:asses_data][:date][:amount][:assesReference][:year][:cusOffCode‌​][:serie][:number][:date][:time]. How is that possible there? It has the same hash structure (xml to nested hash which output similar to my example, or am I wrong?)

Comment: @PenelopeAetherMitsubishi -- well, I've not seen the hash in question, but the logical assumption is that it isn't the same as the hash in your example. I mean that `...[:date]` most likely returns a hash which contains a key `:time`. Or else I don't see how it could ever work.